# Cannot change permissions of the '/' directory in Docker

Tags: docker

I am building a Docker image based on Oracle Linux 6.7.
It seems the default permissions of the `/` directory created is incorrect: 750. I want to change it to 755 but the `chmod` command in the Dockerfile seems to have no effect.

How do I set the permissions of the `/` directory? I have tried adding
`USER root`
in the Dockerfile but that did not work either.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM    oraclelinux:6.7

RUN     ls -ld /
RUN     chmod 755 /
RUN     ls -ld /
```

**Output from `docker build -t oraclelinux:fubar .`**

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM oraclelinux:6.7
 ---> cfc75fa9f295
Step 1 : RUN ls -ld /
 ---> Running in ed83a5c1f462
drwxr-x--- 21 root root 4096 Aug 27 14:41 /
 ---> 2a1f11648594
Removing intermediate container ed83a5c1f462
Step 2 : RUN chmod 755 /
 ---> Running in 6f045908c424
 ---> 1e44793993cb
Removing intermediate container 6f045908c424
Step 3 : RUN ls -ld /
 ---> Running in 0b1b10022e79
drwxr-x--- 21 root root 4096 Aug 27 14:41 /
 ---> f97f3e6711c5
Removing intermediate container 0b1b10022e79
Successfully built f97f3e6711c5
```

If I run the container and change the permissions manually, it works:

**`docker run -ti oraclelinux:fubar`**

```
[root@1e73ebab4b8c /]# ls -ld /
drwxr-x--- 21 root root 4096 Aug 27 14:56 /
[root@1e73ebab4b8c /]# chmod 755 /
[root@1e73ebab4b8c /]# ls -ld /
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root 4096 Aug 27 14:56 /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out after searching on the web that the main problem was about the '/' directory having incorrect permissions and it could not be fixed by simply changing the permissions inside the Dockerfile.

This [post](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12745) suggested that it could be related to `umask` and the bug fix went into the 1.8.0 release. So, the first step was to upgrade the Docker engine. It did not solve the problem.

Another [post](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4068#issuecomment-36383309) suggested that when an image was built on one file system and then used on another, the permissions on the '/' directory are set incorrectly. On the system I was building the image, 'devicemapper' is used. It could be that the image from Dockerhub was built on a different file system.

So, I switched to a different Oracle Linux image, provided by Oracle:

`FROM    oracle/oraclelinux:6.6`

and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me, I'm able to change the permissions and/or I have 755 permissions on my container when I run it.

I would check the permissions in your docker home dir. i.e `/var/lib/docker`

You can can check where the images and also the containers get stored

```
ls -ld /var/lib/docker/aufs/diff
ls -ld /var/lib/docker/aufs/mnt
```

Comment: `/var/lib/docker` has 755.

There is no `/var/lib/docker/aufs` but there is `/var/lib/docker/vfs`.

`/var/lib/docker/devicemapper` has 700.  Inside that directory, there are three sub-directories: `devicemapper` and `metadata` have 700 and `mnt` has 750.